# port.ReadLine() - Not update

Tags: c#, asp.net, arduino, serial-port

I really need your help.

I am building a project with an Arduino Uno and some magnetic sensors. I want the result output of the sensors to be printed and then to read it on my asp.net project (Visual Studio).

I am using `Serial.print` and `Serial.println` to print the string and `port.ReadLine()` to read the string.

The problem is that when I read the string it does not update like it should be (on the Serial monitor in Arduino I can see that it's updating well).

When I am trying to change the ReadLine to Read it's not working either.

[image: Serial monitor]

[image]

"data_arduino" is not getting updated.

Can you help me?

This is the full Visual code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp2 {
    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            SerialPort port = new SerialPort();
            port.BaudRate = 9600;
            port.PortName = "COM3";
            port.DtrEnable = true;
            port.Open();
            bool status1 = true;
            bool status2 = true;
            bool status3 = true;
            char[] arr = new char[4];
            while (true) {
                String data_arduino = port.ReadLine();
                for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++) {
                    char first = data_arduino[i];
                    arr[i] = first;
                }
                int space = arr[0] - 48;
                if (arr[1] == 48)
                    status1 = false;
                if (arr[2] == 48)
                    status2 = false;
                if (arr[3] == 48)
                    status3 = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this will keep reading the same line as far as I can tell, don't you need to tell it to do the last line or something like that? Or should this work like this

Comment: Yes I need the last line. How can I do it?

Comment: I don't know I was just guessing, that why I asked. Maybe check the documentation for `SerialPort.ReadLine()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have excess port.ReadLine() statement here:

```
char first = data_arduino[i];
arr[i] = first;
data_arduino = port.ReadLine(); //Here you read the value you don`t use
```

Remove it and leave only the port.Read() method call at the while loop beginning

Comment: TNX! BUT. I did this but the "data_arduino" always stays with the value of the first line , although it was update (and for example it prints "4111" he still reads it as "5111"